# How to create join table with foreign keys with sequelize or sequelize-cli

Tags: node.js, join, foreign-keys, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm creating models and migrations for two types, Player and Team that have many to many relationship. I'm using sequelize model:create, but don't see how to specify foreign keys or join tables.

```
sequelize model:create --name Player --attributes "name:string"
sequelize model:create --name Team --attributes "name:string"
```

After the model is created, I add associations.
In Player:

```
Player.belongsToMany(models.Team, { through: 'PlayerTeam', foreignKey: 'playerId', otherKey: 'teamId' });
```

In Team:

```
Team.belongsToMany(models.Player, { through: 'PlayerTeam', foreignKey: 'teamId', otherKey: 'playerId' });
```

Then the migrations are run with

```
sequelize db:migrate
```

There are tables for Player and Team but there's no join table (nor foreign keys) in the database. How can the foreign keys and join table be created? Is there a definitive guide on how to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I also have the same question like you, I've searched, but no luck.
This is the way what I did and I modify following your code.
I create migration for join table manually. And I add compound index for both foreign keys.

```
module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable('PlayerTeam', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
    playerId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'Player',
        key: 'id'
      },
      onUpdate: 'cascade',
      onDelete: 'cascade'
    },
    teamId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'Team',
        key: 'id'
      },
      onUpdate: 'cascade',
      onDelete: 'cascade'
    },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    }).then(() => {
      // Create Unique CompoundIndex
      let sql = `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PlayerTeamCompoundIndex"
              ON public."PlayerTeam"
              USING btree
              ("playerId", "teamId");
            `;
      return queryInterface.sequelize.query(sql, {raw: true});
      });
  },
  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('PlayerTeam');
  }
};
```